# Recursion and parameters passed by reference

Tags: java, recursion, parameters, pass-by-reference

Could someone please explain in very simple terms why the code below outputs 35 and not 999 when the array is in essence passed by reference and temp[0] is 999 and passed into someFunction() as num1.

public class TestB
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] num1 = {35};
    someFunction(num1, 3);     
    System.out.println(num1[0]);  //prints 35
}

public static void someFunction(int[] num1, int count){

    if (count!= 0){
        int[] temp = {999};
        someFunction(temp, count-1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Because you reassigned the `temp` variable, not the `temp[0]` element of the array. It's not pass-by-reference, it's pass-by-sharing.

Comment: It's Java.  As I trace through the algorithm, on the second call, num1[0] is 999 and continues to be until I return back to main.

Comment: Java is **never** pass by reference. If you pass `num1` to the `someFunction` method – call it 'method' rather than 'function' – then the value of the reference is copied to `someFunctions` first parameter (which appears to have the same name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someFunction` does not read or write to the `num1` parameter. Thus, `someFunction` **by definition** can't impact the `num1` array passed in to it from `main`.

This would be the case, regardless of whether array parameters in your language of choice were passed by reference or by value.

> As I trace through the algorithm, on the second call, num1[0] is 999
>   and continues to be until I return back to main.

I suspect you are getting confused by the fact that your variable name in `main` and your parameter name in `someFunction` are the same. You are seeing `num1` as set to a particular value - but that isn't `main`'s `num1` - that is `someFunction`'s `num1`. To make that clearer when debugging, change the name of one of them (either the variable name in `main` or the parameter name in `someFunction`) to `bob` instead.

In terms of the outcome you are trying to achieve I suspect, that perhaps instead of:

```
public static void someFunction(int[] num1, int count){

    if (count!= 0){
        int[] temp = {999};
        someFunction(temp, count-1);
    }
}
```

you may have meant to write:

```
public static void someFunction(int[] num1, int count){

    if (count!= 0){
        num1[0] = 999;
        someFunction(num1, count-1);
    }
}
```

Note in particular that (with my suggested change) `someFunction` will be writing to the `num1` parameter (the parameter passed in, not a new `temp` array) - so the array in `main` will reflect that change.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Can you explain simply why when you trace the call num1[0] becomes 999?  Are the parameters local to each call?

Comment: The `num1` is `someFunction`'s `num1`. Change the name of one of the `num1`s to `bob` and you'll spot your mistake very quickly.

Comment: Ah apologies I think you answered this point above.  Thank you!